# Type new Email - To, Cc, Bcc displaying Full Email adress instead the Names

Tags: outlook

Creating a new email in Microsoft Outlook,
how can I force the `To`, `Cc` and `Bcc` fields to show the full email adress instead of the names?

As in the picture of the **Example 2** .

**Example 1:** (default)
[image: Displaying Contacts as Name]

**Example 2:** (what i need)
[image: Displaying Contacts as Full Email]

Comment: Is that a programming question? If so, what code did you use for setting the To, Cc, Bcc fields?

Comment: if there is a way to force the contacts (through VBA code) to suppress the nicknames and force the email address to appear instead... that's what I'm trying to understand/find.

Answer (score 1):

The Outlook object model doesn't provide any property or method for that.

I guess the names are displayed because corresponding contacts are kept in your address book (contacts folder). If you remove corresponding contacts from address books you will start getting emails instead of names resolved. Also it makes sense to check one-off entries in Outlook. One-off addresses are used to send messages to one-off recipients, recipients that do not have a corresponding entry in any of the session's address book containers. Clients can create one-off addresses when they add new entries to the address book or new recipients to the recipient list of an outgoing message. See [One-off addresses](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/outlook/mapi/one-off-addresses) for more information.

Also Microsoft Outlook maintains the `AutoComplete list`. The list is used by both the automatic name-checking feature and the automatic completion feature. The `AutoComplete list`, also known as the `nickname cache`, is generated automatically when you send email messages from Outlook. The list contains SMTP addresses, LegacyExchangeDN entries, and display names for people to whom you have sent mail previously.

Comment: yes, at the moment, it seems to be the only way.. but in the emails I receive, the contacts always appear in a different way than the one I have configured in my contact list.

Comment: Check out the autocomplete list and one-off addresses.